# Check system is Little Endian OR Big Endian

Tags: 16.04, cpu, system

How to check which Byte Order my system is Using ?

Little Endian OR Big Endian ?

Comment: Same question on ServerFault: [How to tell if a Linux system is big endian or little endian?](http://serverfault.com/q/163487/403609)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Byte Order can be checked by viewing the information about CPU.

Run this command,

`lscpu | grep "Byte Order"`

You will get to know your Byte Order.

Comment: There is no need to use `sudo` ;)

Answer (score 9):

You can also use Python:

```bsh
python -c "import sys; print(sys.byteorder)"
```

It will print either `little` or `big`.

Comment: please change `python` to `python2`

Comment: Or just make it version independent by adding parentheses: `print(sys.byteorder)`